# docker: Error response from daemon: grpc: the connection is unavailable

Tags: docker, opensuse

Anyone have any idea what's causing this error? Is it going to be something to do with my network settings?

(bit of a noob on networking front, please feel free to comment and point me in the right direction for relevant data)

Get it when trying to do:

- any `docker run` commands
- any `docker build` with package updates (e.g `RUN apk update`)

**Specs:**

- `Docker version 1.13.0, build 78d1802`
- `openSUSE Tumbleweed 20170505`

**Testing issue**

Tried running the following containers to no avail:

- `Redis:latest`
- `alpine:latest`
- `python:3.4.6`
- `python:latest`
- `hello-world`

**Edit:**

Docker service running fine - `systemctl status docker` returns:

```
docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: active (running) since Wed 2017-05-17 16:21:18 BST; 2 days ago
```

From `docker inspect`, containers are exiting with:

- `Exitcode 128`
- `"Error": "grpc: the connection is unavailable"`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fixed!

Ran `systemctl restart docker`

No idea what the problem was...

Comment: I need to do this after every system restart. Did you manage to find the root cause of the problem?

Comment: @ZerefeL never happened again so had no need to. This github issue (https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/31849) shows several potential reasons (one being kernel issues), this talks about container not being properly removed (http://www.fatalerrors.org/a/rpc-error-code-14-desc-grpc-the-connection-is-unavailable.html), this one talks about firewall issues - specifically with iptables (https://forums.docker.com/t/error-response-from-daemon-rpc-error-code-unavailable-desc-grpc-the-connection-is-unavailable/39066/8)...

Comment: well this seems to be the fix :(

Comment: For me this is was the cause: Apr 03 21:07:30 ci dockerd[17760]: time="2019-04-03T21:07:30.523402100Z" level=error msg="libcontainerd: error restarting containerd: fork/exec /usr/bin/docker-containerd: cannot allocate memory" - so make sure you have enough free memory - when this happens I have to restart docker, no recovery when RAM is freed.

Answer (score 2):

For history: another possible reason is that on older versions docker containers fail to start due to corrupted `events.log` (`/var/run/docker/libcontainerd/containerd/events.log`), removing the file fixes the issue. See [containerd#1699](https://github.com/containerd/containerd/issues/1699) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Activate debug mode in running daemon**
{debug =true}
**2. Reload the daemon configuration**
basically, kill it, restart the docker.

```
systemctl restart docker
```

The error should be solved now permanently